# Search and replace composed Unicode characters

Tags: shell-script, sed, find, unicode

I have a deep folder structure on a Debian machine
where the directory names and the filenames
contain some "special" characters (`ä`,`ö`,`ü`). 
However, these are not in "ISO-8859-1"
but in a Unicode-combined-character form. 
So as I learned, that's a simple `a`
along with the two dots (diaeresis/umlaut)
as "separate" characters.

I tried to bulk rename all files and folders by using find and sed:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Files - normal characters
find . -depth -name "*[äöüÄÖÜ]*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo $1 | sed -e "s/ä/ae/g; s/ö/oe/g; s/ü/ue/g; s/Ä/Ae/g; s/Ö/Oe/g; s/Ü/Ue/g")"' _ {} \;
# Files - Unicode combining characters
find . -depth -name "*[äöüÄÖÜ]*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo $1 | sed -e "s/ä/ae/g; s/ö/oe/g; s/ü/ue/g; s/Ä/Ae/g; s/Ö/Oe/g; s/Ü/Ue/g")"' _ {} \;

# Directories - normal characters
find . -depth -type d -name "*[äöüÄÖÜ]*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo $1 | sed -e "s/ä/ae/g; s/ö/oe/g; s/ü/ue/g; s/Ä/Ae/g; s/Ö/Oe/g; s/Ü/Ue/g")"' _ {} \;
# Directories - Unicode combining characters
find . -depth -type d -name "*[äöüÄÖÜ]*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo $1 | sed -e "s/ä/ae/g; s/ö/oe/g; s/ü/ue/g; s/Ä/Ae/g; s/Ö/Oe/g; s/Ü/Ue/g")"' _ {} \;
```

However, it seems that `find` also selects all occurrences of `a`
in a file/folder name
if the `ä` in the `-name` parameter is a combined Unicode `ä`
instead of ISO-8859-1. 
For example,

```
$ find . -name "*[ä]*"  //<-- one letter ä
./filename_one_letter_ä
$ find . -name "*[ä]*"  //<-- combining letter ä
./filename_with_just_a
./filename_one_letter_ä
./filename_with_combining_diaeresis_ä
```

Therefore, the `sed` is passing the filenames through unchanged,
and so `mv` complains when I ask it to rename,
e.g., “`Baustand`” to “`Baustand`”
(i.e., source and destination are the same).

How can I search and replace all combined Unicode `ä`,`ö`,`ü`,`Ä`,`Ö`,`Ü` in a file/folder structure on a Linux system
if I am not able to search for them with find? 
Is there another approach I could try?

An example of my file and directory names is:

```
/Projekte/03-11_Törggel_Mammern/Baustand/03-11_Törggel-Baustand_190501_0009.jpg
```

Which I would want to rename to

```
/Projekte/03-11_Toerggel_Mammern/Baustand/03-11_Toerggel-Baustand_190501_0009.jpg
```

The output of `echo $LANG` is `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Can you provide sample hierarchy structure and the result you expect?

Comment: Doesn't this work?: `find . -name "*[ÄÖÜäöü]*" -exec bash -c 'mv {} $(echo {} | sed -e "s/ä/ae/g; s/ö/oe/g; s/ü/ue/g; s/Ä/Ae/g; s/Ö/Oe/g; s/Ü/Ue/g")' \;`. On my end it works fine. Also before doing a move command it is always recommended to use `echo` before, like this: `find . -name "*[ÄÖÜäöü]*" -exec bash -c 'echo $(echo {} | sed -e "s/ä/ae/g; s/ö/oe/g; s/ü/ue/g; s/Ä/Ae/g; s/Ö/Oe/g; s/Ü/Ue/g")' \;` :)

Comment: You’re asking a very broad question, and then revealing that you know quite a bit about how to solve it.  So I can’t tell what you’re actually asking — where are you stuck?  Is the problem that ``find`` is finding files with ***no*** non-Roman (accented) characters, and that, therefore, the `sed` is passing the filenames through unchanged, and so `mv` complains when you ask it to rename “`Baustand`” to “`Baustand`” (i.e., source and destination are the same)?  Or is the problem that ``find`` isn’t finding the files that *do* have special characters in their names?

Comment: @Bog I don't see a huge difference to my attemp?
@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'
I try to clarify a little: The "core" problem is, that ```find``` is finding files with non-combined-letters when I search for combined letters. See example here: https://pst.innomi.net/paste/pcx5a9w6sncoxmvg3ug2guk6

Comment: (1) So, is it what I said: that the command accomplishes the renames that you want it to do, but that it *also* give you a million error messages about trying to rename a file to itself? (2) What do you get when you try ``-name "*ä*"`` (using the combining characters without the square brackets)? For good measure, also try `-iname` with that. (3) BTW, when you use ``-name "*[ä]*"``, does it match (find) files whose names contain “`ö`” or “`ü`” (but not “`a`”)?

Comment: For your information, Stack Exchange honors only one @-ping per comment (the first one), so I didn’t get notified about your response to me.  It’s better to post separate responses to different people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t reproduce this (or even test it) ATM, but…

Well, you know that `[xyz]` matches `x` ***or*** `y` ***or*** `z`. 
I guess that, when you say `[äöü…]` (using the combining characters),
it is seeing

- `a`
- (combining) `¨`
- `o`
- (combining) `¨`
- `u`
- (combining) `¨`
- …

and so it finds files
whose names include `a`, `o`, `u` ***or*** (combining) `¨`,
but not necessarily `ä`, `ö` or `ü`.

So try looking for them separately:

```
find . -depth -name "*ä*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed -e "s/ä/ae/g")"' _ {} ';'
find . -depth -name "*ö*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed -e "s/ö/oe/g")"' _ {} ';'
find . -depth -name "*ü*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed -e "s/ü/ue/g")"' _ {} ';'
find . -depth -name "*Ä*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed -e "s/Ä/Ae/g")"' _ {} ';'
find . -depth -name "*Ö*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed -e "s/Ö/Oe/g")"' _ {} ';'
find . -depth -name "*Ü*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed -e "s/Ü/Ue/g")"' _ {} ';'
```

(without square brackets). 
Note that your `echo $1` (without quotes) could fail for some filenames. 
(`';'` is equivalent to `\;`; I prefer to avoid backslashes stylistically.)

Or, if you *really **really*** want to do it all in one command, try

```
find . -depth "(" -name "*ä*" -o -name "*ö*" -o -name "*ü*"     \
               -o -name "*Ä*" -o -name "*Ö*" -o -name "*Ü*" ")" \
       -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(printf "%s" "$1" | sed -e "s/ä/ae/g; s/ö/oe/g; s/ü/ue/g; s/Ä/Ae/g; s/Ö/Oe/g; s/Ü/Ue/g")"' _ {} ';'
```

(`printf "%s"` is functionally very similar to `echo`, but safer. 
Stylistically, I would normally use `printf '%s'` (with single quotes);
I use double quotes here
because we're inside a single-quoted (`'mv …'`) string.)

And maybe

```
… "(" -iname "*ä*" -o -iname "*ö*" -o -iname "*ü*" ")" …
```

will work.

---

Also, the thing you tried initially might work
if you set `LANG` to `de_DE.UTF-8`.

Comment: And, as [Bog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/515636/bog) pointed out in a comment that’s been deleted: It’s a good idea to back up the directory in which you want to rename the files.  It makes recovering way easier if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much. What you described in the first place was exactly the problem. I didn't consider that [äöü…] matches also a/ä and the combining characters. I could solve it looking for the characters seperately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [`de-ASCII` transliteration](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/main/icu4c/source/data/translit/de_ASCII.txt) of `uconv` will do what you want. For instance with the precomposed and decomposed as well as uppercase and lowercase versions of the `ä` character:

```
$ printf '\u00c4 \u00e4 A\u0308 a\u0308\n'
Ä ä Ä ä
$ printf '\u00c4\u00e4A\u0308a\u0308' | uconv -x name
\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS}\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A}\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A}\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}
```

```
$ printf '\u00c4\u00e4A\u0308a\u0308 \u00c4 A\u0308 \u00c4B\n' | uconv -x de-ASCII
AeaeAeae AE AE AEB
```

(also note the `Ä` changed to either `AE` or `Ae` depending on context).

So, here, you could try and convert all files with non-ASCII characters in their name with something like (in zsh):

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n $'(**/)(*[^\1-\177]*)' '$1$(print -rn -- $2 | uconv -x de-ASCII)'
```

Example:

```
$ touch $'\u00c4\u00e4A\u0308a\u0308'
$ touch $'St\ue9phane' $'Ste\u301phane'
$ zmv -n $'(**/)(*[^\1-\177]*)' '$1$(print -rn -- $2 | uconv -x de-ASCII)'
mv -- ÄäÄä AeaeAeae
mv -- Stéphane Stephane
mv -- Stéphane Stephane
```

Remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy.

Or to avoid running one `uconv` per file in case you have millions to rename.

```
files=(**/*[^$'\1-\177']*)
typeset -U basenames=($files:t)
typeset -A translation
print -rNC1 -- $basenames | uconv -x de-ASCII |
  for name in $basenames; do
    IFS= read -rd '' translated && translation[$name]=$translated
  done

zmv -n $'(**/)(*[^\1-\177]*)' '$1${translation[$2]-$2}'
```

As an answer to your more generic question of how to find files with characters with diaeresis in their decomposed form, you only need to look for the combining diaeresis character (U+308).

So:

```
find . -name $'*\u0308*'
```

Or if it has to follow only one of AOUaou:

```
find . -name $'*[AOUaou]\u0308*'
```

For the ones in their precomposed forms, you'd need to list them all individually:

```
find . -name '*[ÄËÏÖÜäëïöüÿŸǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǞǟȪȫ΅ΐΪΫΰϊϋϔӒӓӚӛӜӝӞӟӤӥӦӧӪӫӬӭӰӱӴӵӸӹḦḧḮḯṎṏṲṳṺṻẄẅẌẍẗ⍡⍢⍣⍤⍥⍨⍩⸚]*'
```

Or:

```
find . -name $'*[\uA8\uC4\uCB\uCF\uD6\uDC\uE4\uEB\uEF\uF6\uFC\uFF\u178\u1D5\u1D6\u1D7\u1D8\u1D9\u1DA\u1DB\u1DC\u1DE\u1DF\u22A\u22B\u385\u390\u3AA\u3AB\u3B0\u3CA\u3CB\u3D4\u4D2\u4D3\u4DA\u4DB\u4DC\u4DD\u4DE\u4DF\u4E4\u4E5\u4E6\u4E7\u4EA\u4EB\u4EC\u4ED\u4F0\u4F1\u4F4\u4F5\u4F8\u4F9\u1E26\u1E27\u1E2E\u1E2F\u1E4E\u1E4F\u1E72\u1E73\u1E7A\u1E7B\u1E84\u1E85\u1E8C\u1E8D\u1E97\u2361\u2362\u2363\u2364\u2365\u2368\u2369\u2E1A]*'
```

Using zsh's `$'\uXXXX'` notation now supported by a few other shells including bash.